# Claimed issue with polynomial interpolation for Reed Solomon

Tags: error-correcting-codes

The wiki article for Reed Solomon error correction includes the following statement near the end of this section:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction#Syndrome_decoding

"The advantage of looking at the syndromes ... Another possible way of calculating e(x) is using polynomial interpolation to find the only polynomial that passes through the points (α[j], S[j]) ... however, this is not used widely because polynomial interpolation is not always feasible in the fields used in Reed–Solomon error correction. For example, it is feasible over the integers (of course), but it is infeasible over the integers modulo a prime [citation needed]."

The statement is tagged as "citation needed".

However I find articles and posts at SO about polynomial interpolation in finite fields, at least for finite fields based on GF(p^n) where n is > 1. I'm wondering if n == 1, such as GF(929), used for some bar codes, can be an issue in some cases.